Error on some PCs in sending String parameter from Delphi 10.3 to DLL created by Delphi 7.0
I have a DLL file created in Delphi 7.0 like this:
Function TransInvoices(JSONText : PWideChar) : PChar; stdcall;
var
  dm : TdmData;
Begin
  dm := TdmData.create(Nil);
  Try
    Result := dm.Trans(JSONText); // Call Function in DataModule
  Finally
    FreeAndNil(dm);
  End;
End;
   
exports
  TransInvoices;

I called this DLL file in Delphi 10.3 like this:
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons;

Function TransInvoices(JSONText : PWideChar) : PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'trans.dll';

type
  TTransFrom = class(TForm)
    TitlePanel: TPanel;
  End;

On my development PC and other PCs that have Delphi installed on them, it works good. But a problem happens with PCs that don't have Delphi installed on them. The error message is:

The code execution cannot proceed because borlndmm.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

If I don't call the DLL file, and comment it:
// Function TransInvoices(JSONText : PWideChar) : PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'trans.dll';

Everything works good.
So, where is the problem?

You need to remove the ShareMem unit from uses in the dll. See: Sharing Memory

The code shown is fine, and certainly has no problem with passing strings.
The real "problem" is simply that your DLL has a compile-time dependency on the DLL version of Borland's memory manager. As such, you will have to deploy borlndmm.dll along with trans.dll on every PC. If you don't want to do that, you will have to recompile the DLL to remove that dependency.

I don't know why but it seems that due to the type of parameters you use (PWideChar) the compiler is adding references to the "SharedMem" unit for you (Borlndmm.dll).
You can check the documentation for more information: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Sharing_Memory

Pointers to WideChar (PWideChar) do not require SharedMem, and the compiler doesn't ever add dependencies. TIt's highly unlikely that the IDE added the dependency, unless other code that we can't see causes it to be added. I've never once (having used Delphi since 1.0 was released) had the IDE add ShareMem for me. I've read documentation that said I would have to add it if I did certain things (like share objects between Delphi code and a Delphi dll).
